# python pandas resample apply with bin start and bin width

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series look like this

```
  index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01 00:00:00', periods=9, freq='T')
  index = index.append(pd.date_range('2000-01-01 00:11:00', periods=5, freq='T'))
  index = index.append(pd.date_range('2000-01-01 00:17:00', periods=5, freq='T'))
  series = pd.Series(range(len(index)), index=index)
```

as you can see i purposely leave some hole in time index, so that when I resample, the start or end of the sample bin may not fall on an existing index value.
what I would like to achieve is like this,

```
series.resample(freq).apply(time_weight)
```

in my `time_weight` function, I would like to weight average value by how far away from that sample bin start, divided by sample bin width, which is `freq` in `timedelta`. But there seems no way to know the start of the the sample bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the weights first:

```
# create dataframe for easy manipulation
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': series}).reset_index()

# sample frequency
freq = '5T'

# groupby
groups = df.groupby(df['index'].dt.floor(freq ))

# base and weights:
df['base'] = groups['index'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0].floor('5T'))    
df['weight'] = (df['index'] - df['base']).dt.total_seconds()

# apply:
groups.apply(lambda x: x['val']*x['weight']/x['weight'].sum())
```

Output:

```
index                  
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0      0.000000
                     1      0.100000
                     2      0.400000
                     3      0.900000
                     4      1.600000
2000-01-01 00:05:00  5      0.000000
                     6      1.000000
                     7      2.333333
                     8      4.000000
2000-01-01 00:10:00  9      0.900000
                     10     2.000000
                     11     3.300000
                     12     4.800000
2000-01-01 00:15:00  13     0.000000
                     14     3.111111
                     15     5.000000
                     16     7.111111
2000-01-01 00:20:00  17     0.000000
                     18    18.000000
dtype: float64
```